# i have a switch statement but i dont know how to change it to how i need it

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a switch statement where the first case is "" as I want to check if the string is empty. My problem is that I need another case which is able to check if there is something within the variable, 'sName', but I don't know how to write this out.

You can ignore what is within the cases but the case in bold that contains dashes is the one I need changing.

(relevant code)

```
string sName = "";
int iChoice = 0;
switch (sName)
{
    case "":
        Console.Clear();



        Console.WriteLine("You are not yet logged in, would you like to create a new account?\n");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("PLEASE NOTE: IF YOU ATTEMPT TO CREATE A NEW ACCOUNT WITH AN EXISTING NAME, YOUR PREVIOUS DATA WILL BE OVERWRITTEN!");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("\n1. Create a new account");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Login");
        iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (iChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                //outputs text to the console
                Console.Write("What is your name? ");
                //stores user input into variable sName
                sName = Console.ReadLine();
                //outputs text to the console
                Console.Write("\nWhich school do you work at? ");
                //stores user input into variable sSchool
                sSchool = Console.ReadLine();
                //outputs text to the console
                Console.Write("\nWhat class do you teach? ");
                //stores user input into variable sClass
                sClass = Console.ReadLine();

                //outputs the user's name
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou are now logged in as " + sName + "\n");

                //creates a new text file using the users name
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sName + ".txt"))
                {
                    //writes to the text file using the variables
                    sw.WriteLine(sName);
                    sw.WriteLine(sSchool);
                    sw.WriteLine(sClass);

                }
                Console.Clear();
                displayMenu();
                iOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                break;


            case 2:
                //outputs text to the console
                Console.Write("What is your name? ");
                //stores user input into variable sName
                sName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                displayMenu();
                iOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.Clear();
        displayMenu();
        iOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        break;

    ***case --------------------------------:***
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("You are already logged in as " + sName);

            Console.WriteLine("You are not yet logged in, would you like to create a new account?\n");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("PLEASE NOTE: IF YOU ATTEMPT TO CREATE A NEW ACCOUNT WITH AN EXISTING NAME, YOUR PREVIOUS DATA WILL BE OVERWRITTEN!");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\n1. Create a new account");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Login");
            iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is perform two different actions depending on whether `sName` contains an empty string or not, then I wouldn't use `switch`/`case` at all. `if`/`else` is made for the job:

```
if( sName == "" ) {
    // sName is empty
} else {
    // sName is not empty
}
```

If you do want to use a `switch` for some reason, you'd use `default` for the non-empty condition, like this:

```
switch( sName ) {
    case "":
        // sName is empty
        break;
    default:
        // sName is not empty
        break;
}
```

Either way will do exactly the same thing, but as you can see the `if`/`else` is quite a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you dont need to use a switch, "If" should be good enough